# How do I create or move a Tkinter widget when a checkbutton is clicked but the widget has to be in two different places based on what is clicked?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

[image: The layout I'm going for with the place layout]

So I'm trying to create a tkinter GUI and I want an `entry` widget to appear in one location if 'Yes' is selected on a list, and then an alternate location if 'No' is selected. I am also having a problem with clearing my `entry` boxes and removing the widgets that appear when 'Yes' is selected. It is supposed to be a interest collecting form that writes info input by the user to send an email to them after directing them to other resources and such. Is there an alternate way I should go about handling the logic other than `if` statements? I am relatively new to python and I got to this point and I don't know how to solve it.

```
import pandas as pd 
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import shutil
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import font
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('1511Application.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
#writing bulk data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [''], 'Email': [''], 'Subject': [''], 'Message': [''], 'Grade': [''], 'Mechanical': [''], 'Electrical': [''], 'Marketing': [''], 'Graphic Design': [''], 'Programming': [''], 'Chairmans': ['']})
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

writer.save()

root = Tk()
root.title('FIRST team 1511 - Rolling Thunder Student Interest Form')
root.iconbitmap('1511Icon.ico')
root.geometry("800x500+0+0")
photo = PhotoImage(file="1511logo3.png")
teamlogo = Label(root, image=photo)

Titlefont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=14, weight='bold')
font.families()

tk.Label(root, text="FIRST Team 1511 - Rolling Thunder \n Student Interest form", font=Titlefont).place(x=150, y=20)
tk.Label(root, text="Name:", bg='red3', fg='black', width=25,height=1).place(x=130, y=80)
tk.Label(root, text="Email:", bg='red3', fg='black', width=25, height=1).place(x=130,y=110)
tk.Label(root, text="Have you been in FIRST before?", bg='red3', fg='black', width=25, height=1).place(x=130,y=170)
tk.Label(root, text="Grade:", bg="red3", fg='black', width=25, height=1).place(x=130,y=140)
interest_label = tk.Label(root, text="What are you most interested in?", bg="red3", fg="black", width=25, height=1)
interest_label.place(x=130,y=200)


#dropdown event handling
def selected(event):
    global other_expand_failsafe2
    entrydisplay = clicked.get()
    if 'Yes' in entrydisplay:
        
        global extrainfo
        extrainfo = tk.Entry(root, width=32)
        extrainfo.place(x=312,y=201)
        extra_label = tk.Label(root, text='If yes, what team and level of FIRST?', width=28, height=1, bg='red3', fg='black')
        extra_label.place(x=110, y=200)
        interest_label.place(x=130,y=230)
        interest_mechanical.place(x=311, y=228)
        interest_electrical.place(x=311, y=248)
        interest_marketing.place(x=311, y=268)
        interest_design.place(x=311, y=288)
        interest_programming.place(x=311, y=308)
        interest_chairmans.place(x=311, y=328)
        interest_advocacy.place(x=311, y=348)
        interest_leadership.place(x=311, y=368)
        interest_video_production.place(x=311, y=388)
        interest_social_media.place(x=311, y=408)
        other_checkbox.place(x=311, y=428)
        extrainfo_on = "1"
    else:
        #This is for when "No" is selected and Other is checked
        other_expand_failsafe = "1"
        extrainfo_on = "0"


#entrybox next to other checkbox
def expand():
    other.set("1")
    other_expand = other.get() #other=1 basically
    global other_entry
    global other_entry1
    if "1" in other_expand:
        other_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
        other_entry.place(x=371, y=430)
    if "1" in other_expand and other_expand_failsafe:
        other_entry.place(x=371, y=430)

def OtherClear():
    if '0' in other_expand_failsafe2:
        other_entry.place(x=798, y=400)


def ExtraInfoClear():
    if  "1" in extrainfo_on:
        extrainfo.place(x=312,y=201)
        extra_label.place(x=110, y=200)
    else:
        pass

def Submit():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [f"{name.get()}"], 'Email': [f"{email.get()}"], 'Subject': ['Thanks for coming to our event!'], 'Message': ['Test'], 'Grade': [f"{int(grade.get())}"], 'Mechanical': [f"{mechanical.get()}"], 'Electrical': [f"{electrical.get()}"], 'Marketing': [f"{marketing.get()}"], 'Graphic Design': [f"{design.get()}"], 'Programming': [f"{programming.get()}"], 'Chairmans': [f"{chairmans.get()}"]})
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('1511Application.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = load_workbook('1511Application.xlsx')
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'1511Application.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader)+1)
    writer.close()
    name.delete(0, END)
    email.delete(0, END)
    FIRST.delete(0, END)
    grade.delete(0,END)
    extrainfo.delete(0,END)
    interest_mechanical.deselect()
    interest_electrical.deselect()
    interest_marketing.deselect()
    interest_design.deselect()
    interest_programming.deselect()
    interest_chairmans.deselect()
    interest_advocacy.deselect()
    interest_leadership.deselect()
    interest_social_media.deselect()
    interest_video_production.deselect()
    other_checkbox.deselect()
    #set failsafe2 to 0 to hide entry box
    other_expand_failsafe2 = "0"
    OtherClear()
    ExtraInfoClear()


def Clear():
    name.delete(0, END)
    email.delete(0, END)
    clicked.set(options[1])
    grade.delete(0, END)
    interest_mechanical.deselect()
    interest_electrical.deselect()
    interest_marketing.deselect()
    interest_design.deselect()
    interest_programming.deselect()
    interest_chairmans.deselect()
    interest_advocacy.deselect()
    interest_leadership.deselect()
    interest_social_media.deselect()
    interest_video_production.deselect()
    other_checkbox.deselect()
    extrainfo.delete(0, END)
    other_entry.delete(0,END)
    #set failsafe2 to 0 to hide entry box
    other_expand_failsafe2 = "0"
    OtherClear()
    

submit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", width=10, command=Submit, padx=10, pady=10, bg='red3', fg='black')
submit_button.place(x=20, y=450)

clear_button = tk.Button(root, text="Clear Form", width=10, command=Clear, padx=12, pady=10, bg='red3', fg='black')
clear_button.place(x=570, y=450)


info = StringVar()
name = tk.Entry(root, width=30, textvariable=info)
name.place(x=311,y=81)


email = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
email.place(x=311,y=111)
#DROPDOWN BASE CODE
options = [
    'Yes',
    'No'
]

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(options[1])
#ENDS ABOVE
FIRST = tk.OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options, command=selected)
FIRST.place(x=311, y=165)

grade = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
grade.place(x=311, y=140)

mechanical = IntVar()
electrical = IntVar()
marketing = IntVar()
design = IntVar()
programming = IntVar()
chairmans= IntVar()
advocacy = IntVar()
leadership = IntVar()
video_production = IntVar()
social_media = IntVar()
other = StringVar()
other.set("0")

interest_mechanical = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Mechanical", variable=mechanical)
interest_electrical = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Electrical", variable=electrical)
interest_marketing = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Marketing", variable=marketing)
interest_design = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Graphic Design", variable=design)
interest_programming = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Programming", variable=programming)
interest_chairmans = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Public Speaking/Chairmans", variable=chairmans)
interest_advocacy = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Government Advocacy', variable=advocacy)
interest_leadership = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Leadership', variable=leadership)
interest_video_production = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Video Production', variable=video_production)
interest_social_media = tk.Checkbutton(root,text='Social Media', variable=social_media)
other_checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Other', variable=other, command=expand)

interest_mechanical.place(x=311, y=198)
interest_electrical.place(x=311, y=218)
interest_marketing.place(x=311, y=238)
interest_design.place(x=311, y=258)
interest_programming.place(x=311, y=278)
interest_chairmans.place(x=311, y=298)
interest_advocacy.place(x=311, y=318)
interest_leadership.place(x=311, y=338)
interest_video_production.place(x=311, y=358)
interest_social_media.place(x=311, y=378)
other_checkbox.place(x=311, y=398)


teamlogo.place(x=520, y=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Switch to a grid layout. This will make moving widgets much easier. When a row is added or removed, the other widgets will move automatically.

Comment: Sorry that i wasn't specific, but I need the place layout to get the certain look/format I am trying to achieve. I'll try and update it with a picture of what I'm gojng for.

Comment: better use `grid()` or `pack()` to automate position. And if you want to move many elements then put them in `Frame` and then you have to move only frame

Comment: maybe better show expected result when you select different values.

Comment: what means `problem with clearing my entry boxes`? Describe it. Don't expect that we will run code to see it.

Comment: you have error `name 'extrainfo' is not defined`. You should create `extrainfo = None` at start and later check `if extrainfo is not None:` before you try to clear it. OR you should create entry at start - even if you don't need it at start - but not show it at start.

Comment: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)  - ie, all functions directly after imprt (before `root = Tk()`), `lower_case_names` for functions, `global` at the beginning of functions, etc. - all this makes code more readable.